# How to compare the length of fields in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a field called name.

I want to list the names with length more than 3 and less than 10.

> select * from mytable where len(name) > 3 and len(name) < 10

This is not working.

Comment: Is the name field a fixed length or variable length field?  Example: CHAR vs. VARCHAR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CHAR_LENGTH instead. Like this:

```
select * from mytable where CHAR_LENGTH(name)> 3 and CHAR_LENGTH(name) < 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name FROM <TableName> WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(name) > 3 AND CHAR_LENGTH(name) < 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server/Sybase, then the question is fine.

If you are using DB2 / MySQL, then use `length`

```
select * from mytable where length(name) > 3 and length(name) < 10
```

For DB2 and MySQL, there is also [CHARACTER_LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_character-length) although the DB2 version allows you to [specify the unit](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0023193.htm) (MySQL version measures characters in a multi-byte string).